# Error when using isinstance(sample_list,list) in python 3.x

Tags: python, built-in

When I run `isinstance(names,list)` where names is a list, instead of getting True as the result, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    isinstance(names,list)
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

I am using IDLE and Python 3.x

Could anybody please point out what the problem is.

Comment: Show the code when the error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

Because you probably created a variable named `list` somewhere above in your code.

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
...
names = ['Joe', 'Jack', 'Jane']
...
if isinstance(names, list):
   ...
```

---

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

Never use type names such as `set`, `list`, `file`, `dict` etc. as a variable name in your code.